# WSGI / Apache clarification

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have a Pyramid application running on apache with mod_wsgi.
What exactly is the lifeline of my application when a request is made?
Does my application get created (which entails loading the configuration, creating the database engine) every time a request comes in? When using paste serve, this isn't the case. But with mod_wsgi - how does it work? When does the application "terminate"?

Answer (score 1):

For a start, read:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/03/python-interpreter-is-not-created-for.html
  http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/03/load-spikes-and-excessive-memory-usage.html
  http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading

Initialisation is not done on a per request basis. In generally the application should persist in memory between requests. In the case of embedded mode then you may be at the mercy of Apache as to when it recycles processes.

Comment: thank you - that makes sense. however, i need to run some code when my application exists - how and where do i do that?